# Why I am getting TypeError While trying to data cleaning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean data but I am getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\hayyi.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 45, in 
> train["comment"]=train["comment"].apply(CleanText)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
> line 4357, in apply
> return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py",
> line 1043, in apply
> return self.apply_standard()
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py",
> line 1098, in apply_standard
> mapped = lib.map_infer(
>
> File "pandas_libs\lib.pyx", line 2859, in
> pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
>
> File "C:\Users\hayyi.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 32, in CleanText
> comment=processQues(comment)
>
> File "C:\Users\hayyi.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 19, in processQues
> chat = re.sub('((www.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','',chat)
>
> File "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\re.py", line 210, in
> sub
> return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

How can I solve this ?

My Code :

```
train=pd.read_csv("toxic.csv")

def processQues(chat):
chat = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','',chat)
chat = re.sub('@[^\s]+','',chat)
chat = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', chat)
chat = re.sub('\[\d+\]+', ' ', chat)
chat = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', chat)
chat = re.sub(r'[\!:\?\-\'\"\\/]', r'', chat)
chat = chat.strip('\'"')
return chat


stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def CleanText(comment):
comment=processQues(comment)
comment = nltk.word_tokenize(comment)
w = [wd for wd in comment if wd not in stop_words]
return " ".join(w)

train["comment"]=train["comment"].apply(CleanText)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: and make a [mre] please.

Comment: Ah sorry. I am posting now --posted

Comment: Do you have any `nan`s in that column?

Comment: No I don't have any.